# Is it possible to pass formatting expression?

Tags: rust

For example, I have a very simple struct which contains only a float, but I want to implement the `Display` trait for this struct while also be able to set precision for the float inside of the struct...
Sorry I'm very bad at describing things, here's the sample code:

```rust
struct NewFloat(f64);

impl std::fmt::Display for NewFloat {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.pad(&self.0.to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test: NewFloat = NewFloat(0.046);
    println!("{:.2}", test);    // 0.
    println!("{:.2}", 0.046);   // 0.05
}
```

I'd prefer printing `test` giving me same result as printing `0.046`, which applies precision to floating points only and also rounds the number, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delegate to the existing implementation for field:

```
impl std::fmt::Display for NewFloat {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.0.fmt(f)
        // or, for more explicitness:
        // std::fmt::Display::fmt(&self.0, f)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b67f7ddb5e104fe30ad7a8e4069ebc8)

Comment: Oh, didn't know you can do that! Thank you very much.